# Converting a const char * to std::string

Tags: c++, string, char

I've got a `const char *` returned from a processing function, and I'd like to convert/assign it to an instance of `std::string` for further manipulation. This seems like it should be straight-forward, but I've not been able to find any documentation showing how it should be done. Obviously, I'm missing something. Insights appreciated.

Comment: It's one of the constructor options, ``std::string(const char* cstr)``

Comment: `std::string s = f();`

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: Wow, -5. I didn't think it was a terrible question... Oh well.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`std::string`has a constructor from`const char *`.This means that it is legal to write:

```
const char* str="hello";
std::string s = str;
```

Comment: Just make sure that your char * isn't NULL, or else the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 23):

Try

```
 const char * s = "hello";
 std::string str(s);
```

will do the trick.

Comment: I find it amusing that we chose the same example string and almost the same(just swapped) variable names :-)

Comment: Just make sure that your char * isn't NULL, or else the behavior is undefined.

Comment: How is it going to be null?

Comment: @EdHeal It's not in your example, but a char* in general could be.  I'm leaving a disclaimer for others.  For example, I'm using the getenv() function.  If the environment variable doesn't exist it will return a null.  A check would be needed before constructing a string of that function's return value.  This is relevant since OP says they "got a const char * returned from a processing function".

Answer (score 4):

You've got a lot of options:

```
const char* dosth() { return "hey"; }

string s1 = dosth();
string s2 (dosth());
string s3 {dosth()};
auto   s4 = (string)dosth();
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb8ede377fa7b819), [Documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

Note that `s3` and `s4` are C++11 features, if you should still work with an old or non-compliant compiler you would have to work with one of the other options.

Comment: Please add a note that some of the examples require c++11

Comment: Just make sure that your char * isn't NULL, or else the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

`std::string` has a constructor that converts `const char*` implicitly. In most cases, you need to do nothing. Just pass a `const char*` where a `std::string` is accepted and it will work.

Comment: Just make sure that your char * isn't NULL, or else the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

There are three possibilities. You can use a constructor, an assignment operator or member function `assign` (if do not take into account member function `insert` though it is also can be used:) )`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const char * f() { return "Hello Fletch"; }

int main()
{
   std::string s1 = f();

   std::string s2;
   s2 = f();

   std::string s3;
   s3.assign( f() );

   std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
   std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
   std::cout << s3 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Just make sure that your char * isn't NULL, or else the behavior is undefined.